# Inserting carriage return after x amount of characters in a file - red hat command line

Tags: command, line, redhat

I've been trying to work out how to insert a carriage return after a certain amount of characters within a file which is a very long string of characters, and have worked out how to do it, using another query like this I found online.

```
sed 's/.\{2400\}/&\/g' jeffdavis > jdavis184
```

That will insert a carriage return after every 2400 characters, and save to a new file called jdavis184.

However I need to go a step further, in the file I'm doing it to the next application we want to make will fail if any of the words in the string are split. e.g.:

In our file we often have the string

```
null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
```

If the carriage return is inserted like this (following example), then the next application for the file will work fine

```
null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
```

However if the line is split like the following example, we can't use it

```
    null,null,null,null,null,null,null,n
ull,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
```

So I'm trying to work out if I can adapt the command in order to make sure that the carriage return is only inserted before or after the nearest , after the character limit is hit?

Comment: you'd need to "look around" at your potential split point, and find the nearest `,`.

Comment: me and a friend have been working on this line - sed 's/.\^.{2400}.*?[^A-Za-z0-9]/&\/g' input-file > output file - still with no joy.

Comment: For your purposes, it looks like you could simply insert a newline after every comma and be done with it.

Comment: Was finally resolved by identifying a word that must appear in the middle of every string and inserting the carriage return. sed 's/values/\'$'\n values/g' input file > outputfile (where "values" is the word to split the line at).